# GetNetworkInterfaces() returns hundreds of results on Windows Server 2008 R2 Core

Tags: java, windows, networking

Using a simple Java class to get a list of the network interfaces on a Windows 2008 R2 Server Core machine returns hundreds of results.

Sample code being used is per the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html

On Windows 2008 Server Core R2 there are hundreds of GUIDs generated for the registry key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}

Sample:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\{001E146A-E6BB-424E-ACD9-156527A67C59}\Connection]
"DefaultNameResourceId"=dword:00000709
"DefaultNameIndex"=dword:00000247
"Name"="Local Area Connection* 583"
```

There are hundreds of these and GetNetworkInterfaces lists them all - e.g. for the one above it shows "Name=net583". These are not actual network interfaces and it takes a long time to process all of these.

Installing SP1 prevents further GUIDs from being generated but even after I deleted the unwanted GUIDs from the registry GetNetworkInterfaces is still listing them.

Is there any where else on a Windows machine apart from the registry key above where GetNetworkInterfaces() retrieves information about the network interfaces?

We have a web application that uses GetNetworkInterfaces and it can take up to 10 minutes for the web server to start because of the delay in processing all of these non-existent network interfaces.

Comment: Why does your application use getNetworkInterfaces()? Can you eliminate that?

Comment: Our application uses GetNetworkInterfaces() to distinguish between loopback adapters, virtual adapters and adapters that are down. We cannot avoid using it.

Comment: Why does your application need to distinguish between loopback adapters, virtual adapters, and adapters that are down?

Comment: The application talks to a network management card and communication between our app and the management card will not work if we are using a loopback adapter for example. The point is that we need to use getNetworkInterfaces() - we cannot remove it. I had seen in other posts that Java gets the list of network adapters from the registry but I'm not sure that this is the case.

Comment: Maybe I should re-phrase the question as where does GetNetworkInterfaces() retrieve the information on network adapters from on a Windows OS?